# Is the map $f:V_1\times V_2\times....\times V_d\to V_1\otimes V_2\otimes....\otimes V_d$

Tags: tensor-products

Is the map $f:V_1\times V_2\times....\times V_d\to V_1\otimes V_2\otimes....\otimes V_d$ defined as $$f((v_1,v_2,...,v_d))=v_1\otimes v_2\otimes ....\otimes v_d$$linear and/or multilinear?

Here $v_1\otimes v_2\otimes ....\otimes v_d: V_1^{*}\otimes V_2^{*}\otimes....\otimes V_d^{*}\to \mathbb{K}$ ($\mathbb{K}$ being the underlying field) is a map $$v_1\otimes v_2\otimes ....\otimes v_d(f_1,f_2,...,f_d)=f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2)...f_d(v_d)$$ where $f_i\in V_i^{*}.$

**My Attempt:**

I will do my computations when $d=2$ although the argument can be generalized to arbitrary $d.$ So in order to show that $f$ is linear, we pick $x=(v_1,v_2)$ and $y=(v'_1,v'_2)$ in $V_1\times V_2$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$ then we want to show that $f(\alpha x+y)=\alpha f(x)+f(y).$ $$f(\alpha x+y)=((\alpha v_1+v'_1,\alpha v_2+v_2) )=(\alpha v_1+v'_1)\otimes (\alpha v_2+v'_2).$$

Now for any tuple (f_1,f_2) we have that $(\alpha v_1+v'_1)\otimes (\alpha v_2+v'_2)(f_1,f_2)=f_1(\alpha v_1+v'_1)f_2(\alpha v_2+v'_2).$

However $(\alpha f(x)+f(y))(f_1,f_2)=\alpha (v_1\otimes v_2)+(v'_1\otimes v'_2)(f_1,f_2)=\alpha (f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2))+f_1(v'_1)f_2(v'_2).$

Clearly, both expressions are not the same so I think that this map is not linear.

Regarding multilinearity, we consider $$f((v_1+\alpha v'_1,v_2))(f_1,f_2)=((v_1+\alpha v'_1)\otimes v_2)(f_1,f_2)=f_1(v_1+\alpha v'_2)f_2(v_2)=f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2)+\alpha f_1(v'_1)f_2(v_2)$$ which is the same as $$(v_1\otimes v_2+\alpha v'_1\otimes v_2)(f_1,f_2)$$ and so $f$ is multilinear.

Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes it's correct, it's multilinear but not linear.

Comment: Not only is it multilinear, but it is the *quintessential* multilinear function: every other multilinear function must factor through it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property